# Align enumerate to text and items to numbering for exercises and answers

Tags: align, enumerate, exercises, answers

**Problems:**

1. I wish to align the items to the text for the `exercises`.
2. I wish to move the `a)` so it is directly to the right of the number 1 for `answers`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed,exercisedelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{showframe}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise and answer options
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipBefore}{0pt}

\begin{document}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Exercise}
Some text here \\
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries\alph*)]
  \item $x^{2}+2 x-8$
  \item $x^{2}+2 x+8$
  \item $2 x^{2}+x$
  \item $-3+4 x-x^{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercise}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Answer 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Answer}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries\alph*)]
  \item $(x+1)^{2}-9,(x-2)(x+4)$
  \item $(x+1)^{2}+7$
  \item $2\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{8}, 2 x\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$
  \item $1-(x-2)^{2},-(x-1)(x-3)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{Answer}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Prints out exercises and answers
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Exercises}
\shipoutExercise
\section{Answers}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

To have the items align to the text on the left for the exercises and let the enumerate list begin directly to the right of the answer number and then keep them aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've well understood what you want, here is a solution. I've taken the liberty to add a small space after the comma in some answers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed,exercisedelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{showframe}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise and answer options
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipBefore}{0pt}

\begin{document}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Exercise}
Some text here
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries\alph*), wide=0pt]
  \item $x^{2}+2 x-8$
  \item $x^{2}+2 x+8$
  \item $2 x^{2}+x$
  \item $-3+4 x-x^{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{Exercise}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Answer 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Answer}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries\alph*), topsep=0pt, before= \vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
  \item $(x+1)^{2}-9,\:(x-2)(x+4)$
  \item $(x+1)^{2}+7$
  \item $2\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{8},\: 2 x\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$
  \item $1-(x-2)^{2},\:-(x-1)(x-3)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{Answer}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Prints out exercises and answers
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Exercises}
\shipoutExercise
\section{Answers}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update*: Another alignment  for the questions in the exercise part, and a small improvement of the Answers part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed,exercisedelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{showframe}
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise and answer options
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipBefore}{0pt}
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{\textbf{\alph{Question})\ }}
\setlength{\QuestionBefore}{0.67em}

\begin{document}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Exercise}
 Some text here
 \Question $x^{2}+2 x-8$
 \Question $x^{2}+2 x+8$
 \Question $2 x^{2}+x$
 \Question $-3+4 x-x^{2}$
\end{Exercise}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Answer 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Answer}
\begin{enumerate}[\alph*), font=\bfseries, topsep=0pt, leftmargin=2.8em, before= \vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
  \item $(x+1)^{2}-9,\:(x-2)(x+4)$
  \item $(x+1)^{2}+7$
  \item $2\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{8},\: 2 x\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$
  \item $1-(x-2)^{2},\:-(x-1)(x-3)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{Answer}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Prints out exercises and answers
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Exercises}
\shipoutExercise
\section{Answers}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the exercises and the answers in two columns, you can use the `tasks` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed,exercisedelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{showframe}
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise and answer options
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipBefore}{0pt}

\begin{document}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Exercise}
 Some text here
\begin{tasks}[label-format=\bfseries](2)
 \task $x^{2}+2 x-8$
 \task $x^{2}+2 x+8$
 \task $2 x^{2}+x$
 \task $-3+4 x-x^{2}$
\end{tasks}
\end{Exercise}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Answer 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Answer}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}
\begin{tasks}[label-format=\bfseries](2)
\task $x^{2}+2 x-8$
\task $x^{2}+2 x+8$
      \task $2\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{8},\: 2 x\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$
      \task $1-(x-2)^{2},\:-(x-1)(x-3)$
\end{tasks}
\end{Answer}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Prints out exercises and answers
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Exercises}
\shipoutExercise
\section{Answers}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is correct for Answers but for Exercises the items should be left aligned with the text "Some text here".

Comment: Oh! I didn't understand it that way. So, for instance `a)` should be under `S`?

Comment: Yes sir, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the `\Question` command?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - how would I go about to use it with the `exercise` package?

Comment: It is defined by the package, and I've finally found how to customise it. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: I think I managed to figure out a solution as well - but not reached the crossing line yet. I did first `\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}.}` and then I added `\Question{Some text here}`. However, the question number is indented and I'm not sure how to align it always to the left.

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact  code?

Comment: This looks excellent - is there a way to have a) and b) next to each other and c) and d) next to each other below a) and b)?

Comment: Do you mean they should be closer, or that b) and c) should be  a little farther apart (verticall)? Or that these pairs should be on the same line?

Comment: I meant that a) and b) on row 1, c) and d) on row 2

Comment: Please see if my update is what you want.