# Adaptive column size based on width of tasks

Tags: exercises, tasks, answers, column-width

**Problem:**

This issue is related to the following post: [Align enumerate to text and items to numbering for exercises and answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500021/align-enumerate-to-text-and-items-to-numbering-for-exercises-and-answers/) - but it deals with a different aspect of the package `tasks`, namely how to get tasks to adapt in width.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed,exercisedelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tasks}
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise and answer options
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\noindent{\textbf{\ExerciseHeaderNB}} \ExerciseTitle}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipBefore}{0pt}
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{\textbf{\alph{Question})\ }}
\setlength{\QuestionBefore}{0.67em}

\begin{document}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Exercise 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Exercise}
 Some text here
 \Question Question 1 here
\end{Exercise}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Answer 1
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{Answer}
    \vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}
    \begin{tasks}[label-format=\bfseries](4)
        \task $x<-2$
        \task $x>2$
        \task $(x \leq 1) \vee (x>2)$
        \task $0<x<3$
    \end{tasks}
\end{Answer}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Prints out exercises and answers
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Exercises}
\shipoutExercise
\section{Answers}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

Adapt width of all options so that option `c)` may fit in one row.

Comment: The simplest would be to have smaller margins, if you don't want  to use marginal note. Just loading `geometry` does that by default. Other than that, set the number of columns to $3$.

Comment: I can't use `geometry` because it will create a ripple of undesired changes in the document. Setting the column number to `$3$` generates a lot of errors. Is there any other way to solve the width of each task?

Comment: Changing the number of columns shouldn't generate  an error by itself. Could you show the relevant  lines in the .log file? Another possibility is to force answer c) spreading over the last two columns, using `\task*`. In this case, d) will go to a second row, under a).

Comment: For some reason, column c) does not seem to get wide enough. Is there an option to decide how wide each column can be?

Answer (score 1):

The columns of `tasks` cannot adapt to the items. The available width always is split evenly.

Either use less columns, e.g., `\begin{tasks}(2)` or `\begin{tasks}(3)`, or let the third item span two columns:

```
\begin{tasks}(4)
  \task $x<-2$
  \task $x>2$
  \task*(2) $(x \leq 1) \vee (x>2)$
  \task $0<x<3$
\end{tasks}
```